# Reduce counter target value daily until zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter, reduce

Any idea how I can automatically set the value to the difference of a future date and the date today? I am struggling to get this code work.

```
<span class="count">200</span>
<span class="count2">200.7</span>
<span class="count" id="reducedaily">1000</span>

const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
const firstDate = new Date(2020, 10, 2);
const secondDate = new Date();
const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate - secondDate) / oneDay));
jQuery(#reducedaily).text(diffDays);

jQuery('.count, .count2').each(function () {
  jQuery(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
    Counter: jQuery(this).text()
  }, {
      duration: 4000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function (now) {
        if(jQuery(this).hasClass('count')){
          jQuery(this).text(now.toFixed(0));
        }
        else{
          jQuery(this).text(now.toFixed(1));
        }
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: how about deciding a starting date, then compute the count based on the current date? something like ( 1000 - ( 2020/01/01 ) - today )

Comment: I assume the error with `jQuery(#reducedaily).text(diffDays)` is just a typo in your code sample

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your code - a non-jQuery version seems to work quite alright (though for optics' sake, I'm showing the date difference with more decimals).

```js
const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
const firstDate = new Date(2020, 10, 2);

function update() {
  const secondDate = new Date();
  const diffDays = (firstDate - secondDate) / oneDay;
  
  document.getElementById("x").innerText = (diffDays <= 0 ? "no" : diffDays.toFixed(8));
}

setInterval(update, 100);
```

```html
Only <span id="x">some</span> days to go!
```

Comment: Ive updated my code, I guess its sth because of the counter?